# HMAC-SHA512 in Rust, can't get expected result

Tags: rust, cryptography

Trying to get HMAC-SHA512 working in Rust, the test-case is taken from [kraken API](https://docs.kraken.com/rest/#section/Authentication/Headers-and-Signature), but just can't get it working for a few days now.

Can anybody spot what I am missing?

I tried different HMAC libraries, and they all seem to yield the same result, so it seems it's something about how I concatenate/combine strings before feeding it to HMAC implementation.

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
urlencoding = "2.1.0"
base64 = "0.13.0"
ring = "0.16.20"
sha256 = "1.0.3"
```

```
use ring::hmac;
use sha256;
use urlencoding::encode;

pub fn api_sign(
    private_key: Option<String>,
    nonse: u64,
    params: Option<String>,
    uri: String,
) -> hmac::Tag {
    let private_key = match private_key {
        Some(p) => p,
        None => panic!("Private key is not provided"),
    };
    let encoded_params = match params {
        Some(p) => encode(&p[..]).into_owned(),
        //         Some(p) => p, <= tried this one too
        None => "".to_string(),
    };

    let nonse = nonse.to_string();
    let hmac_data = [nonse, encoded_params].concat();
    let hmac_data = sha256::digest(hmac_data);
    let hmac_data = [uri, hmac_data].concat();

    let key = base64::decode(private_key).unwrap();
    let key = hmac::Key::new(hmac::HMAC_SHA512, &key);

    let mut s_ctx = hmac::Context::with_key(&key);
    s_ctx.update(hmac_data.as_bytes());
    s_ctx.sign()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_api_sign_0() {
        assert_eq!(
            base64::encode(api_sign(
                Some("kQH5HW/8p1uGOVjbgWA7FunAmGO8lsSUXNsu3eow76sz84Q18fWxnyRzBHCd3pd5nE9qa99HAZtuZuj6F1huXg==".to_string()),
                1616492376594,
                Some("nonce=1616492376594&ordertype=limit&pair=XBTUSD&price=37500&type=buy&volume=1.25".to_string()),
                "/0/private/AddOrder".to_string()
            ).as_ref()),
            "4/dpxb3iT4tp/ZCVEwSnEsLxx0bqyhLpdfOpc6fn7OR8+UClSV5n9E6aSS8MPtnRfp32bAb0nmbRn6H8ndwLUQ=="
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is that the APIs you're using are not equivalent. I'll be comparing to the Python implementation as that's what I'm most fluent in.

### misunderstanding of the urlencoding API

Your Rust code takes a string of `params` and urlencodes it, but that's not what the Python code does, [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode#urllib.parse.urlencode) takes a *map* of params and *creates the query string*, the value of `postdata` in the python code is

```
nonce=1616492376594&ordertype=limit&pair=XBTUSD&price=37500&type=buy&volume=1.25
```

but the value of `encoded_params` in your code is:

```
nonce%3D1616492376594%26ordertype%3Dlimit%26pair%3DXBTUSD%26price%3D37500%26type%3Dbuy%26volume%3D1.25
```

it's double-urlencoded. That is because you start from the pre-built querystring and urlencode it, while the Python code starts from the params and creates the querystring (properly encoded).

I think [`serde-urlencode`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_urlencoded) would be a better pick / dependency: it is used a *lot* more, by pretty big projects (e.g. `reqwest` and pretty much every high-level web framework), and it can encode a `data` struct (because serde) which better matches the Python behaviour.

### different sha256 API

`sha256::digest` and `hashlib.sha256` have completely different behaviour:

```
sha256::digest(hmac_data)
```

returns a *hex-encoded string*, while

```
hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest()
```

returns the "raw" binary hash value: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest

That's why the Python code encodes the `urlpath` before the concatenation, `message` is `bytes`, not `str`.

It seems this `sha256` outputs only hex strings, and it seems pretty low-use, so I'd suggest you're also using the wrong crate here, you likely want [Rust Crypto's SHA2](https://docs.rs/sha2/0.10.2/sha2/).

### Recommendation: porting

For this sort of situations where there are available implementations, I would suggest

1. dumping the intermediate values of your and your reference implementation to check that they match, that would have made both the postdata and the digest issues obvious at first glance
2. sticking to following the "reference" implementation as much as you can, until you have something working, once your version works you can make it more rustic or fix the edge cases (e.g. make parameters optional, fix the API, use API conveniences, ...)

Here's a relatively direct conversion of the Python version, I kept your return type of an `hmac::Tag` but I used `ring::hmac`'s other shortcuts to simplify that bit:

```rust
use ring::hmac;
use serde::Serialize;
use sha2::Digest;

pub fn api_sign(uri: String, data: Data, secret: String) -> hmac::Tag {
    let postdata = serde_urlencoded::to_string(&data).unwrap();
    let encoded = (data.nonce + &postdata).into_bytes();
    let mut message = uri.into_bytes();
    message.extend(sha2::Sha256::digest(encoded));

    let key = hmac::Key::new(hmac::HMAC_SHA512, &base64::decode(secret).unwrap());
    hmac::sign(&key, &message)
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Data {
    nonce: String,
    ordertype: String,
    pair: String,
    price: u32,
    r#type: String,
    volume: f32,
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_api_sign_0() {
        let sig = api_sign(
            "/0/private/AddOrder".to_string(),
            Data {
                nonce: "1616492376594".into(),
                ordertype: "limit".into(),
                pair: "XBTUSD".into(),
                price: 37500,
                r#type: "buy".into(),
                volume: 1.25,
            },
            "kQH5HW/8p1uGOVjbgWA7FunAmGO8lsSUXNsu3eow76sz84Q18fWxnyRzBHCd3pd5nE9qa99HAZtuZuj6F1huXg==".into(),
        );
        assert_eq!(
            base64::encode(&sig),
            "4/dpxb3iT4tp/ZCVEwSnEsLxx0bqyhLpdfOpc6fn7OR8+UClSV5n9E6aSS8MPtnRfp32bAb0nmbRn6H8ndwLUQ==",
        )
    }
}
```

you can follow and match the signature function pretty much line by line to the Python code.

Comment: This is way much more comprehensive reply than I ever was hoping for. Thank you, kind stranger.